# Android: create an alarm-like notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I create a notification with NotificationCompat.Builder. I set priority to PRIORITY_MAX, category to CATEGORY_ALARM. I also set the .sound property of the notification and set FLAG_INSISTENT flag, befory using notify() method. It works... but I have two little problems.

The first is the volume that I want to be at the maximum, even if the user set a low volume for notifications. I'm sure it is possible, because the default alarm clock app is able to create notifications with a high volume, even if the user set is low.

Now the second problem. My app receives incoming SMS (even if it isn't the default SMS receiver app) and create a custom notification when messages with some properties (sender and content) are received. This means I have two notifications: from the SMS default app and from my app.

What I don't like is that the sound of my notification is interrupted by the sound of the notification generated by the default SMS app.

I know I can disable the notifications generated by the default SMS app for certain senders, however I prefer to create notifications with a sound that isn't interrupted by other notifications.

Is it possible?